# Custom table view header under section index

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to create a custom table view header which is a simple view with a background color and a label.

The problem is for `iOS` versions prior to `iOS 7.0`. When I create my custom header view it goes under the section index bar which make section letters unreadable (cause my custom header background color is gray).

Is there a way to know the width that takes the section index bar in order to create my custom header frame depending on that value?

I don't really want to hard code my header frame dimensions.

Comment: If you only support iOS 6 or height, you can use the `sectionIndexColor` property of the table view and choose a color that shows up better.

Comment: Yes I only support iOS 6+. The problem with `sectionIndexColor` is that my cells are white and my headers are grey. So if I change the color to contrast with either the cells or the headers, the section index won't be readable in one case. 
The best solution would be to have a way to change the section index background color (when it is not tracked), but it's not available in the API.